# Regex to match exact version phrase

Tags: regex, grep

I have versions like:

```
v1.0.3-preview2
v1.0.3-sometext
v1.0.3
v1.0.2
v1.0.1
```

I am trying to get the latest version that is not preview (doesn't have text after version number) , so result should be:
`v1.0.3`

I used this grep: `grep -m1 "[v\d+\.\d+.\d+$]"`

but it still outputs: `v1.0.3-preview2`

what I could be missing here?

Comment: Seems [working](https://regex101.com/r/dU2lfE/1)

Comment: What is definition of latest version?

Comment: @anubhava vNUMBER.NUMBER.NUMBER

Answer (score 2):

To return first match for pattern `v<num>.<num>.<num>`, use:

```sh
grep -m1 -E '^v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}$' file

v1.0.3
```

If you input file is unsorted then use `grep | sort -V | head` as:

```
grep -E '^v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}$' f | sort -rV | head -1
```

When you use `^` or `$` inside `[...]` they are treated a literal character not the anchors.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `v`: Match `v`
- `[0-9]+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(\.[0-9]+){2}`: Match a dot followed by 1+ dots. Repeat this group 2 times
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

To match the digits with grep, you can use

```
grep -m1 "v[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+$" file
```

Note that you don't need the `[` and `]` in your pattern, and to escape the dot to match it literally.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'match($0,/^v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}$/){print;exit}' Input_file
```

***Explanation of `awk` code:*** Simple explanation of `awk` program would be, using `match` function of awk to match regex to match version, once match is found print the matched value and exit from program.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions match substrings, not whole strings. You need to explicitly match [the start (`^`) and end (`$`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions) of the pattern.

Keep in mind that `$` has special meaning in double quoted strings in shell scripts and needs to be escaped.

The boundary characters need to be **outside** of any group (`[]`).